# Contact Form 7 dropdown value shows required field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

i found an javascript to hide or show an textfield if a specific value is selected in an dropdown.

```
<label> Delivery
[select* drop-down-menu include_blank id:delivery "Yes" "No"] </label>

<label id="deliveryaddress"> Delivery Address
[text* deliveryaddress] </label>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("deliveryaddress").style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById("delivery").addEventListener("change", displayTextField);
  function displayTextField() {

    var dropDownText =  document.getElementById("delivery").value;

    if (dropDownText == "Yes") {
      document.getElementById("deliveryaddress").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("deliveryaddress").style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

If the Value "Yes" is selected the textfield shows up and i can enter in this required field. But if i select "No" its hide. In the background its still an required field on "No". But on "No" its should not be a requiered field.
Hope somebody can help me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it’s even possible to switch between those two states on the client side … I mean, you could surely remove the `required` attribute from the field, but the server-side validation of the AJAX request still won’t care about that much, I suppose. // Maybe check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/, that promises that it can properly handle this situation (_“Required fields can be used inside hidden groups without causing validation problems.”_)

Comment: Thank you very much! All fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to to set/unset required attribute on "yes" or "no" options:

```
if (dropDownText == "Yes") {
  document.getElementById("deliveryaddress").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("deliveryaddress").required = true;
} else {
  document.getElementById("deliveryaddress").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("deliveryaddress").required = false;
}
```

Comment: Dont works for me unfortunately. Its still says its required. I tried the plugin that CBroe mentioned and it works for me. But thanks anyway :)